# How to sort approximate values?

Tags: c, sorting, avr

I have data from a sensor which gives me the distance of 2 types of trains (small and big) per clock cycle. I want to register the number of times the distance is measured then store this value in an array, and sort this array to find how many big trains and small trains have passed.

For example, I will receive from the sensor for train 1 there values (500,500,500,500,500, 502, 523, 500, 500). Because the train is 500 mm away from the sensor for 10 clock ticks. And for train 2 (small train) (500, 500, 500) because the train passes by the sensor for 3 clock ticks.

By knowing how many sensor pulses I got, I can determine the train length.

But how can I sort it properly? The train's pulses are not equal

i.e a big train might have 10 values or 11 values.

This is my following attemps to store the tick counts. Which does not work and I am not able to sort this.

```
        int i=0;
        int counter=0;
        int train[6];

        if(adc_result > 5)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        train[i] = counter;
        sprintf(result, "%d", train[i]);
        USARTWriteChar(result);
        USARTWriteChar("\r\n");
        i++;
```

Comment: You have to decide what the metric is you're going to sort.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  There are only two types of train and the data is different.  So JFDI

Comment: a sensor senses if a train passes. If there is a train it will output say 1. No train the output is 0.

Comment: It outputs very clock cycle. 1 need to count very clock cycle for each train. Then sort it.

Comment: 3 questions:  1)Is the velocity the same for all for all train types traveling by the sensor?  2) Is "train type" synonymous with "train length"? 3) as different types of trains pass by the sensor, are they always in the vicinity of 500mm away?)  The last question is because I am confused by your data example:  `(500,500,500,500,500, 502, 523, 500, 500)`  One additional question, do you mean _every_ clock cycle?

Comment: 1-Yes constant velocity
2- Well, there are 2 trains, the big train had a bigger lenght, the small one a smaller lenght. That's how I identify them
3- Yes they are always at 500mm away.

Comment: What exactly are you sorting then, I assume you are counting the occurrences of how many of each train passes by?  What is your objective?

Comment: I am doing 2 things
1- storing the number of 1s per train.
2- Sort the number of 1's to determine if it was a small train or a big train

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer with as much specificity as your question:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ansi_c.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//Assumption: short train is <= 5 clock cycles long  (simulated as value of 30)
//Assumption: long  train is > 10 clock cycles long  (simulated as value of 50)

int randomGenerator(int min, int max);
static uint32_t temper(uint32_t x);
uint32_t lcg64_temper(uint64_t *seed);

int trainType[2]={0,0};; //[0] counts short, [1] counts long

int main(void) 
{

    int i=0, type;

    while(i++ < 1000)
    {
        //simulated train generator
        type = randomGenerator(0,100);//out of a 1000 cycles will hit 30 and 50 a few times.
        //0==no train has occured, do nothing
        //1==short train has occured, increment short train count
        //2==long train  has occured, increment long train count
        switch(type)    {
            case 30://short train
                trainType[0]++;
                break;
            case 50: //long train
                trainType[1]++;
            default: //all other numbers - ignore
                break;
        }
    }   


    return 0;
}

int randomGenerator(int min, int max)
{
    int random=0, trying=0;
    uint64_t lSeed;

    trying = 1;         
    while(trying)
    {

        srand(clock());
        random = (rand()/32767.0)*(max+1);
        ((random >= min)) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }

    return random;
}
```

Comment: My problem is a little bit different
Let says that I know when any train passes by received a 1.
no train = 0

So when a big train passes, I receive 100 1's (THIS IS APPROXIMATE AND THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART). I might receive 101, 106
A small train will give me 50 1's from the sensor (approx)

I need to sort the amount of 1's received to determine which type of train has passed.

Comment: THIS IS APPROXIMATE. Well, you have to choose what the threshold is at some point, even for approximations. Based on what you have said, I would think x < 60 ==small train; x>=60 == large train is a reasonable set of criteria. Then, as a train passes, if you get 50 '1's, then increment the small train counter. If you get 72 '1's then increment the large train counter.